# Pine script - strategy entry using heikin ashi but strategy tester uses the real price not ha bar open

Tags: pine-script

So the following code in Pine-script on TradingView uses the Heikin-Ashi candle-bar `open` price instead of the actual real open in the strategy tester panel.

**Is there a way to get the strategy tester to use the real price?**

[This link](https://medium.com/@MattGosden/tradingview-bugs-1-heikin-ashi-candles-6c2b8707d8f4) explains the issue further.

```js
//@version=2
strategy("haup", overlay=true)

cci20 = cci(close, 20)
sma10 = sma(close, 10)
source = close
sourcea = open

haclose = (open + high + low + close) / 4
haopen = na(haopen[1]) ? (open + close) / 2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2

fromYear = year > 2016
toYear = year < 2019

longCondition = haopen < haclose
if (longCondition and fromYear and toYear)
    strategy.entry("Long 1", strategy.long)

closeCondition = haopen > haclose
if (closeCondition)
    strategy.close("Long 1")
```

Comment: Hi Steven and welcome to SO! Please provide code of what you have already tried yourself and remember that SO is not a code writing service. Otherwise you risk getting your posts down-voted or closed.

Comment: What do you mean with "real open in the strategy tester panel"?

Comment: Thanks not2qubit .  The code is in original post.  Pine script uses the heikin ashi value in the backtest strategy test panel for the list of trades.  This value is not the true price one would buy or sell at.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this two ways:

1. Use regular candles for strategy back-test and pull HA candles value via code for indicator.
2. Usa HA candles for indicator and pull regular candles values via code, but you need to tell exact price to strategy back-test entries and exits.

So I suggest using option **(1)**.

Use this code to pull *open/close/high/low* of HA candles for your indicator.

```
openHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, open)
closeHA = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, close)
highHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, high)
lowHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, low)
```

Comment: Thanks mikeyy .  I'll think about it.  For the strategy i hoped to use heikin ashi to trigger buy sells but wanted the list of trades to calculate based on the actual price.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Above code allows you that. Define those variables first and then in your buy/sell conditions use closeHA instead of close for claculations. Since you will be using regular candles, strategy backtest will calculate trades automaticly based on regular / real prices, not HA prices.

Comment: Thanks.  It works when the chart style is bar, candles or hollow candles. awesome.

Comment: tickerid:  "syminfo.tickerid"  and period: "timeframe.period" ,  to get whatever the chart is showing

Comment: will this do problem with lookahead i guess? not good for backtesting?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to do it from the "Strategy Properties" tab in the strategy, just select "Fill orders using standard OHLC". But calling security via code works as well. I tested with both code and selecting the checkbox, the strategy backtesting came back with the same results.

[image: Strategy Properties tab]